# Upload images from array of objects (Multer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express, multer

I've been struggling with how to grab the images in an array of objects that looks like this:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const prodcutSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      lowercase: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    details: [String],
    fits: [String],
    compositions: [String],
    sold: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    colors: [
      {
        coverImage: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        hoverImage: String,
        images: [String],
        colorName: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          trim: true,
          lowercase: true,
        },
        colorQuantity: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
          trim: true,
        },
        discount: {
          type: Number,
          default: 0,
          max: 80,
        },
        sizes: [
          {
            sizeName: {
              type: String,
              required: true,
              trim: true,
              lowercase: true,
            },
            sizeQuantity: {
              type: Number,
              required: true,
              trim: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    totalQuantity: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    category: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
      required: true,
    },
    subcategory: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "Subcategory",
      required: true,
    },
    series: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "Series",
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

That is the schema of the object, and i dont know how to add that path for the images in my router, i have it like this:

```
router.post("/", upload.fields([
  {
    name: "coverImage",
    maxCount: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "hoverImage",
    maxCount: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "images",
    maxCount: 3,
  },
]), createProdcutValidation, createProduct);
```

And is always throwing me an "MulterError: Unexpected field" this is how i send it with postman:
[Postman Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzvDc.png)
So what is the problem?

"MulterError: Unexpected field" i always get this error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As files are within an array of objects, `.fields()` cannot detect fields, and it's giving that error (`fieldname` is actually `colors[0][coverImage]` etc., which is then unexpected...).

You could use [`.any()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#any), to process all files, and then you could loop `req.files` and read `fieldname` property to determine which type of file is it, add counter to replace `maxCount`, validate etc.

For example:

```
router.post("/", upload.any(), createProdcutValidation, createProduct);
```

handle and validate:

```
req.files.forEach(file => {
  // handle/validate
  console.log(file.fieldname); // e.g. 'colors[0][coverImage]'
});
```